# Retrieving array of Controllers/Actions

Tags: yii2

Is it possible in Yii2 to retrieve an array containing all controllers and actions for the whole application?

Comment: you can use something like this https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin/blob/master/controllers/RouteController.php#L196

Comment: Thx Manquer for the hint. i Just posted with which solution i ended up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally ended up with:

```
protected function actionGetcontrollersandactions()
{
    $controllerlist = [];
    if ($handle = opendir('../controllers')) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') - 10) == 'Controller.php') {
                $controllerlist[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    asort($controllerlist);
    $fulllist = [];
    foreach ($controllerlist as $controller):
        $handle = fopen('../controllers/' . $controller, "r");
        if ($handle) {
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                if (preg_match('/public function action(.*?)\(/', $line, $display)):
                    if (strlen($display[1]) > 2):
                        $fulllist[substr($controller, 0, -4)][] = strtolower($display[1]);
                    endif;
                endif;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    endforeach;
    return $fulllist;
}
```

Comment: I wanted `ActionRequestFile` to give me `request-file` so I changed one of the lines to this:
`$fulllist[substr($controller, 0, -4)][] = ltrim(strtolower(implode('-', preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $display[1]))), '-');`

Comment: Sounds good improvement, but also depends how you go to use it further down the road

Comment: endforeach;endif; etc looks terrible

Comment: this wont work for extended controllers, for instance if i am using a blog module and extended the controller from the base controller i.e from the vendor directory and just add my new custom action to the extended class, it will only get the new action defined and not all the actions for that class.

Answer (score 4):

I started with the answer from Andreas Hinderberger, and just fine tuned it.  I ended up with something like this:

It uses `FileHelper` to get all the files recursively, which is useful if you are extending controllers from base classes.  It also formats the controller-id/action-id using `Inflector::camel2id` so they will match your routes.

```
public function getAllControllerActions()
{
    $controllers = \yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles(Yii::getAlias('@app/controllers'), ['recursive' => true]);
    $actions = [];
    foreach ($controllers as $controller) {
        $contents = file_get_contents($controller);
        $controllerId = Inflector::camel2id(substr(basename($controller), 0, -14));
        preg_match_all('/public function action(\w+?)\(/', $contents, $result);
        foreach ($result[1] as $action) {
            $actionId = Inflector::camel2id($action);
            $route = $controllerId . '/' . $actionId;
            $actions[$route] = $route;
        }
    }
    asort($actions);
    return $actions;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Yii 2 doesn't have any built-in methods to achieve this. You can only get the current controller and its action.

What's the purpose of it? If you really need this you can write such functionality by yourself.

To get all controllers you should search for a files ending with **Conroller**. And they can be located in different places of application. For example in nested folders, modules, nested modules, etc. So there is more than just one place for search.

To get all actions you should search for all methods prefixed with **action** in each controller.

Also don't forget about attached actions in controller `actions()` method. In framework they are usually ending with **Action**, take a look for example at rest actions. But no one forces you to name it like that, so there is possibility that some external actions can just have different naming convention (for example if you working in team and don't follow this convention).

And you probably need to exclude such folders as **vendor**.

So it's not trivial task, but possible with some inaccuracies. I just don't get it what's the point of that.

Comment: The point of that is to get a list of all controllers with actions to build a database table that contains controllers/actions for each authenticated role that they are allowed to call or not.

Comment: in that case i could predefine the folder which are containing controllers.

Comment: You can try to do this like I described. But for that purpose I think it's better to setup RBAC and configure AccessControl via behaviors() in each controller. This is the standard recommended way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow example walk trought all modules and collect all modules controller actions (no tested):

```
<?php

$controllerDirs = [];
$controllerDirs[] = \Yii::getAlias('@app/controllers');
if ($commonControllerDir = \Yii::getAlias('@common/controllers', false)) {
    $controllerDirs['common'] = $commonControllerDir;
}
foreach (\Yii::$app->modules as $moduleId => $module) {
    /*
     * get module base path
     */
    if (method_exists($module, 'getBasePath')) {
        $basePath = $module->getBasePath();
    } else {
        $reflector = new \ReflectionClass($module['class']);
        $basePath = StringHelper::dirname($reflector->getFileName());
    }
    $basePath .= '/controllers';
    $controllerDirs[$moduleId] = $basePath;
}

$actions = [];
foreach ($controllerDirs as $moduleId => $cDir) {
    $actions[$moduleId][$cDir] = actionGetcontrollersandactions($cDir);
}
print_r($actions);


function actionGetcontrollersandactions($controllerDir) {
    $controllerlist = [];
    if ($handle = opendir($controllerDir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') - 10) == 'Controller.php') {
                $controllerlist[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    asort($controllerlist);
    $fulllist = [];
    foreach ($controllerlist as $controller):
        $handle = fopen($controllerDir . '/' . $controller, "r");
        if ($handle) {
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                if (preg_match('/public function action(.*?)\(/', $line, $display)):
                    if (strlen($display[1]) > 2):
                        $fulllist[substr($controller, 0, -4)][] = strtolower($display[1]);
                    endif;
                endif;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    endforeach;
    return $fulllist;
}
```